# how to use youtube api to retrieve videos using hash tags

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, hashtag

I want to retrieve videos about my website posted in YouTube, so I want them to display on my website. I want to write code using the YouTube API that are posted using hashtags. I want to know how to use the YouTube API for hash tags to get the videos.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you've tried so far, what language your webserver is running, etc?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way for users to tag their videos when they upload a video about your website, and how you can then get those videos by using the API?

Comment: Hi tom         we are developing a website and we want all the videos related to the website which are tagged in youtube using the hash tags so that we can display it in our website

Comment: I don't think you can do this in V3, only in V2.